# How to get rows with distinct first attribute and max second attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
id int,
date datetime
)
```

And in this table are many rows with duplicated `id` and different `data`.
How can I get rows with distinct `id` and max value of `date` for each `id`?
P.s. I'm not a badass in an SQL, so sorry for a stupid question, maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the `id`. Aggregate functions like `max()` apply to each group.

```
select id, max(date)
from table_name
group by id
```